What is $\int_0^{\infty}\sin(ax)\cos(bx)dx$ ? where $a$ and $b$ are constant.
I am solving an E&M problem and I can't get the solution of integration above. I guess it is something to do with residue theorem, but I still can't solve it. Please help...

Hint: $\sin(u+v)+\sin(u-v) = 2\sin u\cos v$

The integral in this setting diverges, but to assign it a value, we can define $$ I(q) = \int_0^{\infty} \sin{(ax)}\cos{(bx)}e^{-qx}dx.$$
Then the integral in the problem can be viewed as $\lim_{q \to 0^{+}} I(q)$. Using the trig identity by @archille, the integral can be computed as $$ I(q) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{a\cdot\left(q^2-(b^2-a^2)\right)}{\left(q^2+(b-a)^2\right)\left(q^2+(b+a)^2\right)} &, a\ne b\\ \dfrac{a}{q^2+4a^2} &, a=b \end{cases}$$
Thus, $$\lim_{q \to 0^{+}} I(q) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{a}{a^2-b^2} &, a\ne b\\ \dfrac{1}{4a} &, a=b \end{cases} $$

Interestingly, $\lim_{b\to a}$ doesn't commute with $\lim_{q\to0^+}$.

yes I noticed. Which is why I has to divide it into two cases. @J.G.

Why the downvote ?

@Sam I don't get the downvote either, seems to me a fair answer, (+1).
